# CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER uses in Insert,Update and Delete URI Android Contacts, Provide direction

Tags: android, android-studio

Problem:
**Can any one suggest me that how to append the flag caller_is_syncadapter in insert, update and  delete URIs in android(Example).**
During working with android contacts syncing(SyncAdpater). 
Your help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

During Research I found answer of the above question,Hope it would useful for you.

**Case 1:** INSERT WITH CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER:

while inserting your contact info with your content provider operation one must append in the working uri. for example:

ArrayList ops = new ArrayList();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name).build());

```
ContentProviderResult[] res = mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

            Uri myContactUri = res[0].uri;

            myContactUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();
```

**Case 2:** UPDATE WITH CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER:

ArrayList ops = new ArrayList();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
                .withValue(RawContacts.DIRTY, 0).build());

```
ContentProviderResult[] res = mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

            Uri myContactUri = res[0].uri;

            myContactUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();
```

**Case 3:** DELETE WITH CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER:
 ArrayList ops = new     ArrayList();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME
                        + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "=?",
                new String[] { o.getPhoneContactId() + "", account.name, account.type }) .build());

```
ContentProviderResult[] res = mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

            Uri myContactUri = res[0].uri;

            myContactUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();
```

Let me know in comments, if some face any problem in doing this thing :) thanks , (: Happy Coding :)

Comment: I have added contact to `com.xiaomy`  account but I am not able to `delete contact  ` using `ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID ` with `ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER` can you help me to get out from  this